# The type Merge.CustomDependencyResolver does not appear to implement Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create generic controller for that i am following this approach(http://jonahacquah.blogspot.in/2011/12/writing-aspnet-mvc-3-generic.html) after completion of coding while running the application i am getting these error(The type Merge.CustomDependencyResolver does not appear to implement Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator), in the Global.asax file. 
This is my Global.asax.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Merge
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(controllerFactory));

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new CustomDependencyResolver()); // I am getting the error in this line 




        }
    }
}
```

can any one please help me to solve this problem, Thank you

Comment: Does your CustomDependencyresolver implements IDependencyResolver or IServiceLocator??

Comment: It will implement IDependencyResolver only :)

Comment: @Viru can you suggest some thing